# How do I setup network connection between two Ubuntu computers using patch cable?

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, dhcp, ip

I am attempting to ssh into an intel NUC mini computer from my laptop. They are connected directly using a Cat5e ethernet cable. Both systems are running Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried setting static IP addresses on both computers but I am not getting any response when I try to ping the NUC.

Here is my /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml file on the NUC:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.150/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

And here is my /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml file on my laptop:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.151/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

I am then configuring both networks by running:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

And then pinging the NUC with:

```
ping 192.168.1.150
```

Am I configuring this wrong? I also know that there is a way to ssh between these two computers by setting up a DHCP server on the NUC along with a static IP address and then I wouldn't have to set up the static IP address on the laptop as well. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this please let me know!

UPDATE: I got it to work using static IP addresses on both computers. Next I would like to know if there is a way to do this without needing to set the static IP address on the laptop because there will be multiple computers logging into the NUC at different times. I know there is a way to do this with a DHCP server on the NUC and was wondering if anyone knows how to set that up? Thanks everyone for all of your help!

Comment: 192.168.0.2/24 is not in the same subnet as the gateway, Please try: 192.168.1.150/24 for one and 192.168.1.151/24 for the other. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please edit with additional information - is there a switch/router in your network, why gateway is in another subnet (hosts are in 192.168.0.0/24 subnet and gateway is in 192.168.1.0/24.) Also it is better never to use first ip in subnet (192.168.0.1) because it could be taken by gateway

Comment: I tried the IP addresses chili555 gave me and it is still not working. I also edited my question, these two computers are connected using a Cat5e ethernet patch cable.

Comment: @AdamDodge with such configuration you don't need gateway (you have non in your network). I suggest to delete it from configuration.

Comment: @Gravemind I removed the gateway from my configuration. It still is not responding to a ping. Thank you for responding and helping me!

Comment: @AdamDodge one more suggestion - clean your netplan file and configure network using legacy way - by editing /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: @Gravemind I wasn't able to get that to work but I realized I was using the wrong ethernet name on the laptop, they both had different names. I am very unexperienced in the network stuff so thank you so much for your help! Do you know what the right way would be to set up a DHCP server on the NUC computer so that I wouldn't have to set up a static IP on each computer that I want to log in with?

Comment: @AdamDodge You don't need DHCP server to set static IP. All you need to do is to set both machines in the same subnet by using proper configuration. To know interface name please do "ip a". To assing static IP address you need to edit file /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Does the lights on the network adapter(s) blink? It was long time ago when we was in need to use [crossover cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) for such connections, but I decided to ask just in case :)

Comment: Do the addresses shown appear correctly in `ip addr show`?

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you guys so much. I have edited my question to show what I ended up using. @Gravemind I meant that I would like to have a way to do this without needing to set a static IP on the laptop because there will be multiple computers logging in over ssh on the ethernet cable and I know there is a way to do that using a DHCP server on the NUC computer. Do you know how to set that up?

Comment: Regarding DHCP - it is easier to buy router or L3 switch  and use it's DHCP, then to setup your own. Then just setup static IP on your NUC, and DHCP method of allocating IP on other hosts.

Comment: Look into isc-dhcp-server or dnsmasq.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. I changed my setup back to the original configuration to use NetworkManager and used the /etc/network/interfaces files for configuration.

This is what my /etc/network/interfaces file looks like for the laptop with ethernet port enp2s0:

```
auto enp2s0 
iface enp2s0 inet static 
address 192.168.1.151 
netmask 24
```

This is what my /etc/network/interfaces file looks like for the NUC with ethernet port eno1:

```
auto eno1 
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 24
```

I also used the following to reboot the interface and enable connection:

```
sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup enp2s0
```

Then, I can see the connection is working by running `ping 192.168.1.150` on the laptop. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can set you network using legacy way - by editing /etc/network/interfaces. First you need to list all your interfaces by `ip a`. Then, you need to edit network file on both machines. It should look like that:

```
name of your interface* auto iface

name of your interface* inet static

address 192.168.1.xxx

netmask 24
```

Then you can do `ip link set name of your interface down && ^down^up`

That will reboot you interface and enable configuration.

Comment: As the user is using netplan, this won't work. It's NetworkManager talk.

Comment: Previously, I suggested to clean netplan file. You don't need such advanced configuration for end-to-end network. In fact, if your won't mess with netplan and just use legacy way - there will be no issue.

Comment: If you wish to use NetworkManager, on a system currently using netplan, you've got to change the /etc/netplan/*.yaml file first.

Comment: I changed my setup to use NetworkManager. This is what my files look like, with the two different ethernet interfaces and IP addresses:

'auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.151
netmask 24'

I also used 'sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup enp2s0' instead of what you recommended. I also changed the .yaml file to the original NetworkManager configuration. It works great now!

Comment: @heynnema actually, it is better to completely get rid of netplan and never use it. It doubles functionality and make system less robust. I always suggest to use legacy way of setup network connection on Debian-like OS.

Comment: @Gravemind I partially agree with you... I'd say use NetworkManager/GUI in a Desktop or wireless configuration, and netplan in servers. Netplan has a learning curve, and they didn't give anybody a crash course before they sprung it on us.